# "[self setNeedsDisplay:YES]" in ViewController crashes  app

Tags: iphone, drawrect

when I try to run [self setNeedsDisplay:YES] in my ViewController it crashes with unrecognized selector sent to instance... is there something I'm doing wrong?

I'm using:

```
-(void) drawRect: (CGRect)rect {

    ///code...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

-setNeedsDisplay: is a method from NSView, UIView doesn't have the (pretty much useless) boolean flag. You must call `setNeedsDisplay` instead. So call (from your view controller):

```
[[self view] setNeedsDisplay];
```

No parameter...

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay:YES]
```

You can send `setNeedsDisplay:` message only to UIView based classes. You can effectively override `drawRect`: message only for UIView based classes.

Comment: there's not much to show yet - I have tried moving [self setNeedsDisplay:YES] to viewDidLoad and the same thing happens. I get a "UIView may not respond to -setNeedsDisplay..." warning too. What I'm trying to do is make a simple drawing view. I have a bunch of CGPoints I need to draw.

Comment: just saw your edit - i think that may be the problem. This is a ViewController I am working with

Comment: well maybe not, because when i'm using self.view it still says, "UIView may not respond to -setNeedsDisplay"

Comment: UIView does not have a method setNeedsDisplay: that is from NSView/AppKit. UIView has no boolean flag, just message setNeedsDisplay (no parameter)